# Implementing generic Borrow transitively for HashMap key lookup

Tags: generics, rust, hashmap, type-conversion

Let's say we have a custom wrapper type `MyType` around a string, which I'll try generalizing later.

`Borrow` is implemented for it to enable looking up with a `&str` key in a hash map:

```rust
use std::{borrow::Borrow, collections::HashMap};

#[derive(Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct MyType(String);

impl Borrow<str> for MyType {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let map = HashMap::from([(MyType("abc".to_string()), 3)]);
    println!("{}", map.get("abc").unwrap());
}
```

This works as expected: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee4b959737569d9df608fed19f697f28)

Now, let's try making `MyType` generic while enabling `Borrow` transitively:

```rust
use std::{borrow::Borrow, collections::HashMap};

#[derive(Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct MyType<T>(T);

impl<T, U> Borrow<U> for MyType<T>
where
    T: Borrow<U>,
{
    fn borrow(&self) -> &U {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let map = HashMap::from([(MyType("abc".to_string()), 3)]);
    println!("{}", map.get("abc").unwrap());
}
```

This doesn't work: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4db2dab58fb9bff07e7b519cefeffb30)

```rust
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Borrow<MyType<_>>` for type `MyType<_>`
 --> src/main.rs:6:1
  |
6 | / impl<T, U> Borrow<U> for MyType<T>
7 | | where
8 | |     T: Borrow<U>,
  | |_________________^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T> Borrow<T> for T
            where T: ?Sized;

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 1 previous error
```

It conflicts with [`impl<T> Borrow<T> for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#impl-Borrow%3CT%3E-for-T) in the standard library.

Is it possible to make this lookup work at all in the generic case without some explicit conversion for the queried key in the callsite for lookup?

Comment: I don't think there is a way.

Comment: I'll likely end up implementing some MyTypeRef and a convenience trait for converting T to MyTypeRef on callsites, but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: I came to realization with Borrow interface even that might not work

Comment: from my experience, implement borrow is always bad idea

Comment: why do you need such feature ?